# El redondeo da un resultado completamente distinto al no utilizar GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

Tengo un problema con el redondeo: al momento de sumar la columna de una tabla (es decir, tengo la tabla que utilizo como encabezado y una tabla detalle que se relacionan por un id), la tabla de encabezado tiene un campo llamado `IVATOTAL` (la sumatoria del iva de la tabla detalle) y es `DECIMAL(15,2)` y en la tabla del detalle tiene que es `ivaDetalle` y es `DECIMAL(15,6)`, si yo lo sumo al campo `ivaDetalle` con redondeo de dos decimales y lo agrupo por id cobro obtengo el mismo resultado de `IVATOTAL`, sin embargo si no utilizo el `Group by` me da una cantidad completamente diferente.

Tabla encabezado:

| idCobro (INT) | IvaTOTAL (Decimal 15,2) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1368.33 |

Tabla Detalle :

| idCobroDetalle (INT) | idCobro(int) | ivaDetalle (Decimal 15,6) | idCuenta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 92.024000 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 578.803200 | 20 |
| 3 | 1 | 595.180800 | 10 |
| 4 | 1 | 102.323200 | 20 |

Obtengo el resultado mismo que el encabezado con la siguiente consulta

```
select  round(sum(ivaDetalle),2)
from encabezado a
join detalle b on a.idCobro = b.idCobro
group by a.idCobro
```

Y con esta consulta obtengo un resultado diferente

```
select  round(sum(ivaDetalle),2)
from encabezado a
join detalle b on a.idCobro = b.idCobro
```

P.D. No sé si el `group by` realiza una función de redondeo o algo por el estilo.

Ejemplo:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8ttibmDHT4HgXF8EDs7Whh/1

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con un resultado diferente? ¿Tienes distintos decimales o el número es otro?

Comment: Hola Patricio, si has de cuenta si hago un sum con el el Group by me da por ejemplo 14334.34, pero si hago el sum sin el Group by me da un valor completamente diferente algo así 14335.22

Comment: Es lógico que tengas diferencias, en una consulta estas redondeando primero y luego sumando y en la otra estas sumando y redondeando al final. En estos casos, dónde buscas un total, es mejor sumar y redondear al final.

Comment: En ambas sumo y redondeo, el detalle es que si quito el group by ya me da una diferencia de centavos y requiero llegar a la misma cantidad, saludos.

Comment: Es que una cosa es redondear cada fila y otra redondear la suma

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Lo se pero necesito obtener el mismo valor sin usar el Group by

Comment: Una cosa, ten en cuenta que el valor correcto es sin el GROUP BY. Si opinas lo contrario, entonces es mejor que sólo utilices 2 decimales para el IVA detalle (ya redondeados).

Answer (score 1):

Bienvenido al mundo de los decimales, tu problema no tiene solución, por que estas sumando cosas distintas, el `group by` redondea a nivel de grupo y el `sum`, suma todo y luego redondea. Si quieres algo consistente, el total se tiene que hacer sobre la misma consulta del detalle, es decir sobre el `group by`:

```
-- Detalle por encIdCobro
select encIdCobro, 
       round(sum(detIVA),2)
       from encabezado
       join detalle 
             on encabezado.encIdCobro = detalle.detIdCobro 
       group by encIdCobro;


-- suma del detalle por encIdCobro
select sum(t.detIVA)
       from (select encIdCobro, 
                    round(sum(detIVA),2) as detIVA
                    from encabezado
                    join detalle 
                         on encabezado.encIdCobro = detalle.detIdCobro 
                    group by encIdCobro
             ) t;
```

Comment: No tampoco el resultado con el Group by es: 437,798.59 y el resultado son el Group by y con tu querrá me da: 437,798.34

Comment: Ahora con el fiddle entiendo dónde está el tema.

Answer (score -1):

Gracias al `GROUP BY` se agrupan por ID por lo que solo te hace una suma, sin el GROUP BY suma todos los IVA en un mismo campo y te devuelve la suma total de todos los IVA.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).